# Getting an error implementing Algorithm Birch

Tags: python, algorithm, cluster-analysis, metrics, hierarchical-clustering

I am using the next code. It seems everything is correct, but i have an error: 'ValueError: Number of labels is 1. Valid values are 2 to n_samples - 1 (inclusive)'

```
param_grid = {'threshold':[0.5,0.3,0.1],'branching_factor':[50,20,10]}  
for threshold in param_grid['threshold']:
    for branching_factor in param_grid['branching_factor']:
        clf = Birch(n_clusters = 4,threshold = threshold,branching_factor = branching_factor)
        clf.fit(birch[['R','M','L']])
        y_pred = clf.predict(birch[['R','M','L']])
        print(threshold,branching_factor,"Indicador CH:", print("Indicador CH:",  metrics.calinski_harabasz_score(birch[['R','M','L']], y_pred)))
```

My dataset is

[image]

The error:

```
ValueErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
 <ipython-input-76-82ba1c2eee8c> in <module>
   5         clf.fit(birch[['R','M','L']])
  6         y_pred =    clf.predict(birch[['R','M','L']])
 ----> 7         print(threshold,branching_factor,"Indicador CH:",      print("Indicador CH:",      metrics.calinski_harabasz_score(birch[['R','M','L']], y_pred)))

 /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster    /_unsupervised.py in calinski_harabasz_score(X, labels)
    286     n_labels = len(le.classes_)
    287 
   --> 288     check_number_of_labels(n_labels, n_samples)
     289 
    290     extra_disp, intra_disp = 0., 0.

  /opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/sklearn/metrics/cluster     /_unsupervised.py in check_number_of_labels(n_labels, n_samples)
     32     """
    33     if not 1 < n_labels < n_samples:
    ---> 34         raise ValueError("Number of labels is %d. Valid   values are 2 "
     35                          "to n_samples - 1 (inclusive)" %  n_labels)
     36 

   ValueError: Number of labels is 1. Valid values are 2 to n_samples -   1 (inclusive)
```

Comment: Needs details.  What is `Birch`?  Is there a specific library you're using?

Comment: I see it is from scikit-learn.

Comment: That said your code doesn't show what the variable `birch` is either.  Could you please post the *full traceback* when asking questions about Python errors?

Comment: Birch is the algorithm from scikit learn.

Comment: And birch[['R','M','L']] is my dataset.

Comment: But what type of object is your dataset?  The traceback would help here since the example is not reproducible.  Otherwise it's not clear where the error is coming from.

Comment: I have just added the dataset. Thank you.

Comment: I'm guessing it's a pandas dataframe?  I'm asking for the *traceback*.  When you get the error, everything from "Traceback (most recent call last):" leading up to the actual error.

Comment: Yes it´s pandas. I´ve added the traceback above.

Comment: The traceback tells something very important.  That the error is coming from [`calinski_harabasz_score`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.calinski_harabasz_score.html).  I don't know what that is or what it does, but it looks like the second argument has to be a list of labels.